# AlphaUserPoints 1.8.9 for Joomla 2.5.x

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

Help to find the component for Joomla 2.5 AlphaUserPoints. On the official site [www.alphaplug.com](http://www.alphaplug.com/index.php/downloads.html?func=fileinfo&id=44) File not available. Now AlphaUserPoints  exists only for Joomla 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently used this ext. you can download it [here](http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php?PHPSESSID=a5ede2b4f198e9b751d196e0f871aef7&topic=317383.0)